# Ext.NET Click Handler string

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I'm trying to use a click handler. My function is as so (these are both in the same class):

```
[DirectMethod]
protected bool Save()
{
      //do work
}
```

and I attempted to call it with:

```
using (Ext.Net.Button yes = new Ext.Net.Button())
{
     // random set up for button

     // failed because it couldn't find namespace
     yes.Listeners.Click.Handler = "Namespace.Class.Save();";

     // attempt 2: removed the first one and assumed that the [DirectMethod] sets
     // it to be Ext.net.DirectMethods.Save();
     yes.Listeners.Click.Handler = "Ext.net.DirectMethods.Save();"

}
```

First failed unable to locate namespace, second failed because "object doesn't support this property or method."

What string do I use to render this? If not by the `Listeners.Click.Handler` way, how else can I do it?

The function is in a custom control that extends `Ext.Net.Window` and the using item is in a function called `Display()` that renders the control.

Per vladsch's response, I have changed it to:

```
 [DirectMethod(Namespace="MyMethods")]
 public bool Save()
 {
      //do work
 }
```

and the handler string is now:

```
 yes.Listeners.Click.Handler = "MyMethods.Save();"
```

when doing so, I get "'MyMethods' is undefined."

Comment: Does switching 'Handler' to 'Fn' help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ext.NET forum post by Daniil](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?10287-CLOSED-get-value-of-controls-created-in-code-behind&p=41167&viewfull=1#post41167)

Using X.GetCmp I was able to retrieve the data. It probably isn't the best way possible (probably a way without postback), but it at least netted the results I needed.

Answer (score 3):

DirectMethod must be public
Also you can define own namespace (instead Ext.net.DirectMethods)
[DirectMethod(Namespace="MyDirectMethods")]